# How to make the QGraphicsView size consistent with the size of the image and the main window?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview

I'm developing a graphic editor with Qt, and using a `QGraphicsView` to display the picture, and need to resize it so that it's consistent with the size of the image and the main window.

The following method resizes the image when I open it :

```
//ui here is Ui::MainWindow* pointer
ui->graphicsView->resize(picture->width, picture->height);
```

It looks normal for small pictures, but when I open a big one, its size becomes more than the size of the window and I can't scroll it.

I can set the size of the `graphicsView` to the maximum of the picture and the main window sizes, but this doesn't solve the problem, because when I make the main window smaller, the picture will keep its size and will be larger than the window, so I think I need to resize the image when resizing the main window.

I know there is the system of signals and slots in Qt, but I can't find the suitable slot of `QMainWindow`.

How to catch the changing of the size of the main window to resize the `graphicsView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just override [resizeEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#resizeEvent)() in `QMainWindow`

> [const QSize &QResizeEvent::size() const](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qresizeevent.html#size)
>
> Returns the new size of the widget.

```
void MyMainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
   // ui->graphicsView->resize(event->size());
   QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
}
```